# Can't download my Facebook Messenger data

Tags: facebook-messenger

I am trying to download all my (Facebook) Messenger data (text and photos), but I can't seem to find out how. An important thing may be that I have a Messenger only account; when I attempt to login at facebook.com I get an error message: "This Account Only Works On Messenger".

So, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is (on a computer): click the gear icon in the upper left corner. Then click on "Download Your Information and finally "Create File".